# Reading settings for Blazor WebAssembly App returns old values

Tags: json, caching, settings, blazor, webassembly

I have two settings files. appsettings.json and web.settings.json. Both need to be read to get some settings.

```
        // read JSON file as a stream for configuration
        var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) };

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => client);

        // the appsettings file must be in 'wwwroot'
        using var response = await client.GetAsync("appsettings.json");
        using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(stream);

        using var webSettingsResponse = await client.GetAsync("web.settings.json");
        using var webSettingsStream = await webSettingsResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(webSettingsStream);
```

After that, I read the settings like this

```
var apiUrl = builder.Configuration["ApiUri"];
```

The first I run the application it reads the correct key and localhost:8002 is set.
But when I change the value in web.settings.json to localhost:8001 (just a port change) it still gives me the old 8002 every time I run the app.

web.settings.json:

- Build Action Content and Copy Always.
- The FIle is in the wwwroot
- If I am running and check the web.settings.json in the bin\Debug\netstandard2.1\wwwroot it is there with port 8001 as a setting

Why do I still get 8002? Is it cached somewhere?

Comment: The browser caches responses, so I would try to clear the browser cache or Disable cache. You can also try to get value from the application.json with `var someConfig = builder.Configuration["JsonPropery:Subproperty"];`.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it was the browser cache. I Enabled the Disable Cache and then did a refresh. Now it is working again. Thanks.